# Factorization of $L$-functions for CM Elliptic Curves

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, l-functions

I saw recently that the $L$-functions of elliptic curves with CM can be factored as a product of simpler $L$-functions. In this question, I'd like to ask why that factorization is significant and what it tells us about the original elliptic curve. Here is the theorem in more detail:

> Let $K$ be an imaginary quadratic field, and let $E$ be an elliptic curve with CM by $\mathcal{O}_K$. Suppose that $E$ is defined over a field $L$ containing $K$. Then the $L$-function of $E$ can be factored as follows:
> $$L(E/L, s) = L(s, \chi_{E/L}) \, L(s, \overline{\chi_{E/L}}) $$
> where $\chi_{E/L}$ is the Grossencharacter of $E$ over $L$.

**My question is:** what is the importance of this factorization? Why is it profound / important? What "underlying truth" about elliptic curves with CM does this theorem reveal?

As an example of what I mean by the last question, here is an example where factorization of $L$-functions has a very nice intuitive meaning: given an abelian number field $K$, you can factor the Dedekind zeta function of $K$ as a product of Dirichlet $L$-functions:
$$\zeta_K(s) = \prod_{\chi} L(s, \chi) $$
where $\chi$ runs over all irreducible characters of $\text{Gal }K/\mathbf{Q}$. The "underlying truth" of this theorem is that since characters are *periodic* functions on the integers, this theorem says that the splitting of primes in abelian extensions is governed by *congruence* conditions. This equality of $L$-functions is a concise way to encapsulate that fact.

Is there a similar interpretation in the case of CM elliptic curves? What concrete information about the arithmetic of $E$ is captured by the fact that you can split up the $L$-function of $E$ into the pieces $L(s, \chi_{E/L})$ and $L(s, \overline{\chi_{E/L}})$?

Comment: The L-function of $\chi_{E/L}$ is well-understood analytically (the properties are very similar to Dirichlet L-functions, although the periodicity of the coefficients is replaced by something much more abstract).

Comment: There are too many things to talk about. You might be interested in having a look at the big picture of Langlands program.

Comment: @reuns That's actually very helpful. Would it be correct to say that the $L$-function of $\chi_{E/L}$ easier to understand because it is purely "number theoretic"? i.e: the definition of $\chi_{E/L}$ isn't too dependent on the arithmetic of $E$; it's mostly constructed using only the data of the number fields $L$ and $K$. So this factorization reduces the study of the arithmetic of $E$ (which is complicated) to just doing pure algebraic number theory with the fields $L$ and $K$ (which is less complicated)?

Comment: Yes in fact you can discard $K$ and keep only the arithmetic of $L$. Hecke (and Neukrich) had elementary proofs but then it was replaced by the adelic stuffs. In every case the good analytic properties (mainly an integral giving the analytic continuation and functional equation) reduce to some (complicated) version of the Poisson summation formula. Also $\zeta(s)^2$ is much more complicated than $\zeta(s)$ when just looking at the coefficients and trying to obtain the properties directly, it is often needed to factorize L-functions as much as possible.